# libreoffice-base not configured yet

Tags: 12.04, ppa, libreoffice, configuration

I have the LibreOffice ppa installed (ppa:libreoffice/ppa) and today I had a problem after updating. I got the following error.

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Ready
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libreoffice-base: Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1: 4.3.0-0ubuntu1 ~ precise1) but 4.3.0-3ubuntu1 ~ precise1 is installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1: 4.3.0-0ubuntu1 ~ precise1) but 4.3.0-3ubuntu1 ~ precise1 is installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1: 4.3.0-0ubuntu1 ~ precise1) but 4.3.0-3ubuntu1 ~ precise1 is installed
  libreoffice-core: Breaks: libreoffice-base (<1: ~ 4.3.0-3ubuntu1 precise1) but 4.3.0-0ubuntu1 ~ precise1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try to use -f.
```

After trying

> sudo apt-get install -f

I got the following output

```
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De status informatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Vereisten worden gecorrigeerd... Klaar
De volgende extra pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  libreoffice-base
Voorgestelde pakketten:
  libreoffice-gcj libreoffice-report-builder unixodbc
De volgende pakketten zullen opgewaardeerd worden:
  libreoffice-base
1 pakketten opgewaardeerd, 0 pakketten nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 0 niet opgewaardeerd.
3 pakketten niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Er moeten 0 B/2170 kB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Door deze operatie zal er 2841 kB extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Wilt u doorgaan [J/n]? 
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van libreoffice-base:
 libreoffice-base is afhankelijk van libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.3.0-0ubuntu1~precise1); maar:
  Versie van libreoffice-base-core op dit systeem is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1.
 libreoffice-base is afhankelijk van libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:4.3.0-0ubuntu1~precise1); maar:
  Versie van libreoffice-base-drivers op dit systeem is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1.
 libreoffice-base is afhankelijk van libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.0-0ubuntu1~precise1); maar:
  Versie van libreoffice-core op dit systeem is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1.
 libreoffice-core (1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1) breaks libreoffice-base (<< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1) and is geïnstalleerd.
  Version of libreoffice-base to be configured is 1:4.3.0-0ubuntu1~precise1.
dpkg: fout bij afhandelen van libreoffice-base (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van libreoffice-report-builder-bin:
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin is afhankelijk van libreoffice-base; maar:Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding volgt op een eerdere mislukking.

  Pakket libreoffice-base is nog niet geconfigureerd.
dpkg: fout bij afhandelen van libreoffice-report-builder-bin (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van libreoffice:
 libreoffice is afhankelijk van libreoffice-base; maar:
  Pakket libreoffice-base is nog niet geconfigureerd.
 libreoffice is afhankelijk van libreoffice-report-builder-bin; maar:
  Pakket libreoffice-report-builder-bin is nog niet geconfigureerd.
dpkg: fout bij afhandelen van libreoffice (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding volgt op een eerdere mislukking.
              Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding volgt op een eerdere mislukking.
                            Fouten gevonden tijdens behandelen van:
 libreoffice-base
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin
 libreoffice
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this problem so the dependencies are solved? Do I have to configure libreoffice-base manually?

Comment: I also have this issue with 12.04. In my case I'm using the repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

I followed a [thread on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239916) to solve this problem. There seems to be a line missing from this maintenance script file:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libreoffice-base.postrm
```

The missing line,

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc
```

needs to be added to the end of the file's **second if** statement, just above the closing **fi**, like so:

```
--divert /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc.noaccess \
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc
fi
```

After adding the line, using (for example):

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/libreoffice-base.postrm
```

restart your computer and remove `libreoffice-base` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-base libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice
```

Once this process completes, restart and execute the following to reinstall libreoffice:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base libreoffice
```

Once libreoffice had been successfully reinstalled, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

without error.

This handful of steps and with additional reference to a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1354557) solved my problem.

Comment: I followed your instruction and changed the file, but after I rebooted and tried to remove libreoffice-base I got the following error message: [http://pastebin.com/Zr14Nv5g]

Comment: @Wicky! I would like to advise, but it seems the content of your pastebin link was removed soon after you posted your comment! I hope you were able to find a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why that happened, this one should be correct: http://pastebin.com/3NxK2GaY

Comment: @Wicky! Yes - the latest pastebin was readable (though in Dutch, it seems?). You might want to try using **aptitude** in place of **apt-get** to both **remove** libreoffice-base and **install** the libreoffice-base and libreoffice packages. For example, run: `sudo aptitude remove libreoffice-base`, restart and then `sudo aptitude install libreoffice-base` - restart again, and then `sudo aptitude install libreoffice` Good luck.

Comment: The `apt-get remove...` didn't work for me - I needed to use the `purge` version as [noted in this bug-report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1354557/comments/11). All quite annoying, but good to have such active help from the wider community.

Comment: @Wicky! @Davïd! This begs a debate under different cover regarding the use of **aptitude** vs **apt-get** - glad you both got it working.

Comment: apt-get purge didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/libreoffice-base.postrm

Add the line:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc
```

to the end of the file's second if statement, just above the closing fi. The new code must be:

```
--divert /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc.noaccess \
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/basic/script.xlc
fi
```

2) Issue the following commands:

```
  sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libreoffice.* /tmp/
  sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libreoffice 
  sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libreoffice-base
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Solution based on:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1354557
http://www.piprime.fr/1480/manually-remove-broken-package-debian-ubuntu/